# Cannot display a random image file in tkinter app

Tags: python, image, random, tkinter

I am trying to write some code that will play a sound, ask the user to identify the correct sound, and then show the image if the user is either correct or wrong. However, when I do so I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\LearnArabic\Program\LearnArabicprogram2.4.1.py", line 42, in <module>
      answers(question, possAnswers)
    File "C:\LearnArabic\Program\LearnArabicprogram2.4.1.py", line 37, in answers
        label = Label(master, image=IL, anchor = E)
     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2760, in __init__
          Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2293, in __init__
          (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
       _tkinter.TclError: image "C:\LearnArabic\alphabet\Image\Dal.png" doesn't exist
```

The program currently opens a blank `tk` window but as the error suggests, no image is displayed. I've tried using png files and gif files but I get the same error. Why doesn't it recognize my file path?

Here is my code:

```
import os, random
from random import choice
import winsound
import time
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

question = "What is the correct Arabic letter?"

Imagepath = "C:\\LearnArabic\\alphabet\\Image\\"
Soundpath = "C:\\LearnArabic\\alphabet\\Sound\\"
Letter = random.choice(os.listdir(Soundpath))
winsound.PlaySound((Soundpath)+ (Letter), winsound.SND_FILENAME)

def answers(question, possAnswers):
    print(question)
    answerList = ["answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "correct"]
    random.shuffle(answerList)

    for i,j in enumerate(answerList):
        print("%s: %s" %(i, possAnswers[j]))

    inp = int(input(">>> "))

    if answerList[inp] == "correct":
        print("Correct!")
        IL = (Imagepath + (Letter.rsplit(".", 1)[0])+ ".png")
        label = Label(master, image=IL, anchor = E)
        label.image = (IL)
        label.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = S)

    if answerList[inp] != "correct":
        print("Try again fool")
        print("The corect answer was: ", Letter)
        IL = (Imagepath + (Letter.rsplit(".", 1)[0])+ ".png")
        label = Label(master, image=IL, anchor = E)
        label.image = (IL)
        label.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = S)

possAnswers = {"answer1" : random.choice(os.listdir(Soundpath)),
               "answer2" : random.choice(os.listdir(Soundpath)),
               "answer3" : random.choice(os.listdir(Soundpath)),
               "correct" : Letter}
answers(question, possAnswers)
```

Comment: `IL` is just a path to the image. You need to _load_ the image yourself with `image = tk.PhotoImage()` and use `image` for the `Label`'s `image=` argument (and save its value in `label.image`).

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the response! after the "print" text I added: Displayimage = PhotoImage(file=IL)
label = Label(master, image=Displayimage, anchor = E)            That resolved the error.

Comment: Andrew: That's good news....you're welcome. Glad it turned out to be nothing more than a relatively simple problem and fix.

Comment: Hi Andrew, if your problem is solved then it may be a good idea to leave an answer on your own question so that future users can use the information to resolve their own issues.

Comment: Sure thing Ethan, hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the answer with the help of martineau. I was missing a line of code using PhotoImage. I updated the two "if" statements int the "def answers" section to read like the following:

```
    if answerList[inp] == "correct":
        print("Correct!")
        IL = (Imagepath + (Letter.rsplit(".", 1)[0])+ ".png")
        Displayimage = PhotoImage(file=IL)
        label = Label(master, image=Displayimage, anchor = E)
        label.image = (Displayimage)            
        label.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = S)


    if answerList[inp] != "correct":
        print("Try again fool")
        print("The corect answer was: ", Letter)
        IL = (Imagepath + (Letter.rsplit(".", 1)[0])+ ".png")
        Displayimage = PhotoImage(file=IL)
        label = Label(master, image=Displayimage, anchor = E)
        label.image = (Displayimage)            
        label.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = S)
```

Hope this helps anyone with a similar question!